# jQuery chained functions and "this": Where is my syntax incorrect in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Here's the situation:

I have 3 `button`s

```
<button type="button" class="job-update-button wp-core-ui button-primary" id="delete-btn">Remove</button>
<button type="button" class="job-update-button wp-core-ui button-primary" id="update-btn">Update</button>
<button type="button" class="job-update-button wp-core-ui button-primary" id="add-btn">Add</button>
```

and an `input`

```
<input type="hidden" name="jobAction" value="" />
```

whose `value` is supposed to relate to the `id` of whichever `button` has been clicked. It might look silly, but this is my way of consolidating the logic on the page so that a single script on the server can handle a bundle of related AJAX requests.

- `delete-btn` clicked --> `jobAction` gets `value` of `delete`
- `update-btn` clicked --> `jobAction` gets `value` of `update`
- `add-btn` clicked --> `jobAction` gets `value` of `add`

The function I'm using for the `click` events starts with

```
jQuery('.job-update-button').click(function(){
    // change the value of the memberAction hidden input based on which member-update-button was clicked
    jQuery('input[name="jobAction]"').val(jQuery(this).attr('id').substring(0, this.IndexOf('-')));
```

and I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting

> this.IndexOf is not a function.

My thinking is that by the time I call `this.IndexOf('-')` the `this` refers to the object invoking `substring`, which is the string returned by `jQuery(this).attr('id')`.

Is that wrong? If so, can you help me understand why? And is there a more efficient and compact way of going about this whole procedure?

Comment: Wouldn't this be bound to the object of the click? You're not creating a new function beyond the click handler. Plus the wrong function name. Plus it's just plain hard to read when you don't pull it out into a variable.

Comment: No this has nothing to do with substring. It has the same value it did when you passed it to jQuery(). Assign the value returned by the attr('id') to a variable and the do your substring and indexOf on that

Comment: "*`this` refers to the object invoking `substring`*" - No, just like the `this` in `jQuery(this)` doesn't refer to the object invoking `.val()`. It is passed as an argument, and has nothing to do with what functions are invoked anywhere. It's bound to the `function() {` scope of the click handler, and refers to the DOM object that was clicked.

Comment: Go for `this.id.split("-")[0]`

Comment: Wouldn't `this.split("-")[0]` be inefficient since it needlessly parses everything after the `("-")` in order to construct the rest of the array?

Answer (score -1):

Your Jquery function is messed up all you need is:

```
$('.job-update-button').click(function(){
// change the value of the memberAction hidden input based on which member-update-button was clicked
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var value = id.replace("-", " ");

    $('input[name="jobAction"]').val(value);

})
```

For starters you dont need to call jQuery the shorthand way is simply **$**
It looks like you have a **"** outta place in your code. Change this:

```
'input[name="jobAction]"'
```

To:

```
'input[name="jobAction"]'
```

[Working codepen example](http://codepen.io/mdan89/pen/zGJEbg/)

Please note instead of:

```
jQuery('.job-update-button').click(function(){}
```

I used:

```
$('.job-update-button').click(function(){}
```

You could call jQuery every time but **$** is easier.

If its not what you're looking for just let me know and I will edit or delete.

Answer (score -1):

Let's break your code down a bit to make it clearer:

```
jQuery('.job-update-button').click( function(){

    var value = jQuery(this).attr('id').substring(0, this.IndexOf('-'));

    jQuery('input[name="jobAction"]').val( value );

});
```

Inside the click event handler, `this` refers to the HTML element that triggered it. That is just the way jQuery works internally (you can explicitly set `this` or 'scope' when [calling or applying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) a function).

That means you are trying to call [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) (note the correct spelling) on an HTML element, which does not have an `indexOf` method.

Also, note that most people use the `$` shorthand for the jQuery method.

To fix your code, this would probably suffice:

```
$('.job-update-button').click( function(){

    $('input[name="jobAction"]').val( $(this).attr('id').replace(/-btn$/, '') );

});
```

Here, I'm using the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in order to strip out the appended '-btn' part of the id.

Comment: User wants ID substring plus name apostrophe is outta place

Comment: oops! have adjusted. cheers @code, didn't see that requirement.